# increase gap between bars in multi category groups

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

[current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnDkj.jpg)I want to increase gap between bars in my SSRS bar chart after every group is finished (e.g. after every month). I have 2 category groups month and level. in each month there are 3 levels and I want to increase gap after 3 columns.
can you please help me?[increase gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eoilk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to increase the gap. However, there are two 'solutions'.
1. Go to the Chart Series Properties -> General -> Custom Attributes, and reduce the point width, perhaps from 0.8 to 0.6. Have a little play until you find something you like.
2. [SSRS: Custom bar width between multi-level categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833783/ssrs-custom-bar-width-between-multi-level-categories) Try something like this. Add a dummy group to your dataset that has no value and turn the labels off.
I would go for number 1 as it is much simpler.